# How browser set html properties?

Tags: html, browser

When an html object is created browser gives it some properties like scrolltop ecc.How does the browser give this properties?Through what language?

Comment: From my understanding this is dependent on how the browser implements the HTML specification. DOM Element properties are handled by the browser and as such are dependent on the implementation of the browser.

Comment: For example scrolltop property could be found through a javascript method or it is calculated by the browser In some way and with javascript we can also see this property?

Comment: The default properties of a DOM element are set by the browser. You (the programmer) can interact with these elements using Javascript.

I.e 

document.getElementById('someId').attributes

Comment: Ok,how does  the browser set this properties?Is there a way to create a javascript method to find for example scrolltop property without asking it to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the browser handles DOM elements internally is completely specific to the browsers implementation of the HTML specification.

You (the programmer) can interact with DOM elements using Javascript.

You can get the scrollTop property of a specific element by using the following javascript:

`var someElement = document.getElementById("someElement");
var scrollTop = someElement.scrollTop;`

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) is a list of DOM element properties and methods.

Comment: I have understood what you want to say but what i don't understand is what type of language browsers use to calculate html's elements properties.For example what language does Firefox use to calculate html's elements properties?Is There a way  to find ,For example ,scroll top value using javascript?

Comment: Oh god sorry.I have read well your Answare and i have understood.Browser doesn't use traditional language to calculate all the properties but it Uses an own language.Have i understood well?

Comment: The code I post above will get the scroll top value of a desired element.

Browsers are programs just like any other application on your computer. As such they are written in standard programming languages. I believe FireFox is written in C++.

Comment: Ok,i have understood.Thanks:):)